# Symfony Forms, formtype label based on a property value of the data object

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

Is it possible to set the label value of a form type to be a property value that is available in the data object?

My FormType class:

```
class ShapeFractionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('value', NumberType::class, [
                'label' => 'name'
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ShapeFraction::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The ShapeFraction data class:

```
class ShapeFraction
{
    public string $name;
    public string $type;
    public float $value;

    // ...
}
```

Rendering the form:

```
$shapeFraction = new ShapeFraction('A', 'length', 10);
$form = $formFactory->create(ShapeFractionType::class, $shapeFraction);

// Render using Twig...
```

The result is a simple form containing a single input with 'name' as label. Is it possible to use the property value of ShapeFraction::$name as the label of the field? Result will become like this: A: <input..>.
I would like to achieve this without using the object data directly in Twig or something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the data that you pass to your form using `$options['data']`.

That means you can do this:

```
/** @var ShapeFraction $shapeFraction */
$shapeFraction= $options['data'];
$builder->add('value', NumberType::class, [
    'label' => $shapeFraction->name
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue. My real case only was more complex. The fractions are part of a shape object. I use the CollectionType to render the fractions. In that case, the data index is not available within the $options array. I created a new question for this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75020710/symfony-forms-fieldtype-label-by-property-of-the-dataobject-within-a-collectio